# (0 , core_1.default) is not a function on lambda handler using @middy/core

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, middy

I'm trying to use middy on my lambda middlewares, my stack is created with TypeScript with Serverless v3, Node.js v18.

There is the minimal reproductive example:

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "outDir": ".build",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "rootDir": "./"
  }
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "handler.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@middy/core": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.91",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.0",
    "serverless-offline": "^13.3.2",
    "serverless-plugin-typescript": "^1.1.7",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

`serverless.yml`:

```
service: serverless-example

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello
          method: get
```

`handler.ts`

import middy from '@middy/core'

const myProtectedFunction= async (event, context) => {

```
  const userId = "123"
  return {
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: `Hello, user ${userId}!` }),
  };
```

};

export const handler = middy()
.handler(myProtectedFunction);

After install serverless & dependencies just execute: serverless offline

and then make the request to the endpoint

Error image:
[image: error get]

Comment: Please give a [mre]. You'd only see `(0, core_1.default)` if you were emitting CommonJS, which isn't what your `tsconfig.json` says.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've tried with "module": "commonjs", but it still throw error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what worked for me:

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "s3-ts-1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@middy/core": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.91",
    "@types/node": "^11.13.0",
    "serverless": "^3.38.0",
    "serverless-offline": "^13.3.2",
    "serverless-plugin-typescript": "^2.1.5",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

Changes:

- specify `type`
- added `serverless` (this was because i have v2 in global scope, so added v3 in project scope)
- updated the packages in dev dependencies

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "target": "es2021",
    "outDir": ".build",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["es2015"],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  }
}
```

Changes: I made some changes from the middy doc [here](https://middy.js.org/docs/best-practices/bundling)

`serverless.yml` and `handler.ts`: No changes

Run command: `npx sls offline` (Because i added local dependency for v3. You might not need npx).

Comment: Hi, I've tried to change the package.json and tsconfig.json, but now i get the error: Cannot use import statement outside a module.
I've checked th doc you've added from middy, but I didn't found nothing to change, what you changed from there?

Comment: Make sure that you added "type": "module" in package.json file. Also make sure that you ran "npm i" or "yarn" to install the updated packages. @SebasBejenaru

Comment: I just removed the .build folder, just to make sure and now it's working :)  thanks for your time!